# set -A invalid in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to feed arguments sequentually using set -A, so I can delete the highest version first and then the base. But I get an error for set command.

Here is the code

```
    _install=$(rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{INSTPREFIXES}\n" | grep MQSeriesRuntime | grep 7.0 | grep -v 7.0.1-0 | sort -r | awk '{print $1}')
 _numver=$(rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{INSTPREFIXES}\n" | grep MQSeriesRuntime | grep 7.0 | grep -v 7.0.1-0 | wc -l)
set -A arrinstall ${_install}

##########################################
# Get a list of all MQ install instances #
##########################################
i=${_numver}
arrayindex=0
while [ i -ne 0 ]
do
  _inst_level=${arrinstall[$arrayindex]}
  _Unum=$(echo ${_inst_level} |  sed -e 's/-/ /g' | awk '{print $2}')
  _Level=$(echo ${_inst_level} |  sed -e 's/-/ /g' | awk '{print $4}')
  i=$((i-1))
  arrayindex=$((arrayindex+1))
done
```

Here is the error I get

```
./test.sh: line 8: set: -A: invalid option
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [arg ...]
./test.sh: line 15: [: i: integer expression expected
```

What am I doing wrong here.

here are the output of variables,

```
$ rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{INSTPREFIXES}\n" |grep MQSeriesRuntime |grep 7.0 | grep -v 7.0.1-0 |sort -r |awk '{print $1}'
MQSeriesRuntime-U860943-7.0.1-12
MQSeriesRuntime-U860173-7.0.1-11

$ rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}\t%{INSTPREFIXES}\n" |grep MQSeriesRuntime |grep 7.0 | grep -v 7.0.1-0 |wc -l
2
```

Comment: What is it that you think `set -A` does?

Comment: Assign the arguments sequentially ?

Comment: Check the documentation.

Comment: updated the post with variables output.

Will check the man page again, but is there anything you can suggest me to change in this if I am using the set command incorrectly.

Comment: `-A` is not a supported option to the `set` command; I'm not sure why you think it is necessary.

Comment: this is what I see on man pages for set

set --help
Usage: set [ options ] [arg ...]
OPTIONS

  -A name         Assign the arguments sequentially to the array named by name starting at subscript 0 rather than to the positional parameters.

Comment: So, your shell is ksh and the script is bash?

Comment: that seems to be my problem. I have incorrect shell I am referencing to. I changed it to korn shell and is now working fine. 

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set -A` is a `ksh` command, but you are executing your script with `bash`. The `bash` equivalent would be simply

```
arrinstall=(${_install})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
set -A array -- values ...
```

is the ksh88 syntax, also recognised by `pdksh` and derivatives, `ksh93` and `zsh` (in `zsh`, the `--` *after* `-A` is not recognised nor needed except in `ksh` emulation), but not `bash`.

```
array=(values  ...)
```

is the zsh syntax (though strictly speaking `rc` with an otherwise non-Bourne syntax, supported it before that), also recognised by bash 2.0 and above, ksh93, yash and mksh (based on pdksh) but [with some major differences between implementations](/a/238129).

In the case of `array=()` (an empty list), in `ksh93`, the variable must have been declared as an array variable beforehand (with `typeset -a`) as that `array=()` conflicts with the compound variable declaration.

As for the `$_install` scalar variable splitting, [that's the Bourne split+glob operator](/q/171346) invoked whenever you leave a variable expansion unquoted in list context, which you generally need to tune beforehand:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline only
set -o noglob # disable the glob part which we don't want here
array=($_install) # invoke split+glob
```

Note that in zsh, split and/or globbing have to be requested explicitly, so:

```
IFS=$'\n'
array=($=_install) # split only, with the $=var operator
```

Though, there, you'd rather use the `(f)` parameter expansion flag to split on linefeeds:

```
array=(${(f)_install})
```

In `bash`, you can use the `readarray` command to get lines into an array:

```
readarray -t array < <(printf '%s\n' "$_install")
```

Or directly:

```
readarray -t array < <(rpm -q...)
```

Also note that while the operands of the `-ne` or other arithmetic `test`/`[` operators are any arithmetic expression in `ksh`, in `bash` (and most other shells), they have to be decimal integers, so while:

```
[ i -ne 0 ]
```

would work in `ksh` as `i` is an arithmetic expression that resolves to the value of the `$i` variable, in `bash`, you'd need:

```
[ "$i" -ne 0 ]
```

(with `$i` quoted so as not to invoke the split+glob operator), or you could use the `ksh` `((...))` arithmetic evaluation operator also supported by `bash` and `zsh`:

```
((i != 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `$` sign while referring to variable `i`

```
i=${_numver}
while [ $i -ne 0 ]
```

This will correct the error

```
"./test.sh: line 15: [: i: integer expression expected"
```

Comment: Note that `[ i -ne 0 ]` would work in ksh, as ksh accepts any arithmetic expression there.